# GitLab Templating: Multiple before_script blocks in default?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

This doesn't work correctly:

template1.yml

```
default:
   before_script:
      - echo "hello from one"
```

template2.yml

```
default:
   before_script:
      - echo "hello from two"
```

.gitlab-ci.yml (the actual pipeline)

```
include:
  - project: 'templates'
    file:
      - 'template1.yml'
      - 'template2.yml'
  
build1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "hello from the pipeline"
```

output (note the output from template1 is missing):

```
Hello from two
hello from the pipeline
```

I understand that GitLab may believe that there is 'ambiguity' in the ordering when merging blocks in to before_script, but it could use the order specified in the 'include'
section of the pipeline.

Does anyone know of a way that I can arbitrarily include templates in my pipeline in such a way that they can contribute to the default 'before_script' block?

It all must run sequentially in the same container (be in the same 'stage')

For example, using yaml anchors requires us to specify the names of the anchors rather than just the file that the anchors were in, so that doesn't work...

Comment: It seems that GitLab CI has no way of creating 'single job' pipelines that will all run in the same container instance.

This means that any changes to the container made by a previous job or stage are lost (yes artifacts can be passed, but what if a previous stage configures the runner container to access some remote system, or installs an app etc.)

There seems to be a need for multiple script blocks in the same STAGE and JOB.
Perhaps just allow the naming of script blocks, so that any job that has multiple script blocks can be merged in alphabetical order?